# Are RegistryKey properties really String objects in powershell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, object, registry

In powershell, it's possible to get an array of `RegistryKeys` as follows:

`$hkeys = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

When I inspect the first element of this array, this is what I get:

```
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall


Name                           Property                                                                                                                    
----                           --------                                                                                                                    
7-Zip                          DisplayName     : 7-Zip 21.03 beta (x64)                                                                                    
                               DisplayVersion  : 21.03 beta                                                                                                
                               DisplayIcon     : C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe                                                                           
                               InstallLocation : C:\Program Files\7-Zip\                                                                                   
                               UninstallString : "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe"                                                                    
                               NoModify        : 1                                                                                                         
                               NoRepair        : 1                                                                                                         
                               EstimatedSize   : 5237                                                                                                      
                               VersionMajor    : 21                                                                                                        
                               VersionMinor    : 3                                                                                                         
                               Publisher       : Igor Pavlov
```

`Property` seemed a little strange, so I looked further into that:

```
> $hkeys[0].property.gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                        
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

The elements in the `property` attribute, since they are delimited by a colon `:` did not seem like strings, so I looked a bit further, but found that they are indeed `String` objects:

```
> $hkeys[0].property[0].gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                        
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Since they appeared to be string objects, I tried to echo the first one. However, it only shows the first part of the string and not the part after the colon:

```
> $hkeys[0].property[0]
DisplayName
```

I feel like there's something fundamental which I don't understand here. Are the elements of the array really `String` objects? If so, why won't the part after the colon appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registry objects have a defined output format which powershell uses when no format is given. You can read more here [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2)

You can test this by calling

```
$hkeys #formated with name:value, actually uses $hkeys | Out-Default

$hkeys | Format-Table Property #value won't show anymore

$hkeys | Format-List #value won't show anymore
```

The default format file for registry (ex: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Registry.format.ps1xml) will display *Property* as following

```
$result = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |
    Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |
    Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()
$result = $result.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($result.Length, 5000) )
if($result.Length -eq 5000) { $result += "..." }
$result
```

and as you've noticed, the output is a `string[]`

To get the actual value in powershell you need to call a method or use `Get-ItemProperty`

```
$hkeys[0].getvalue('DisplayName') #you have to specify the property name
# or
$hkeys[0] | Get-ItemProperty
```